# Do I need a transit visa for Japan?

Tags: transit-visas, japan, filipino-citizens, nrt

I'm holding Philippine passport and I'm here in Canada and I'm going to visit my country  but I need to stop over in Narita Terminal 1 and next day I'm going to transfer Narita Terminal 2. My layover is 17:45 minutes. Do I need a transit visa?

Comment: When is your trip? As per Anish's answer this isn't allowed today, but may be by the time you are travelling.

Answer (score 4):

```
Transit: Passengers are permitted to transit through Japan to the Philippines if they meet all of the following conditions:

They will transit on the same day;
The are arriving and departing from the same airport;
They will not leave the transit area of the airport;
They are not departing with low cost carriers such as Cebu Air (5J). Passengers are permitted to depart with Philippine Airlines (PR), Japan Airlines (JL) or All Nippon Airways (NH).
```

From timatic.

Yes, you will require a visa, as you don't satisfy the first criteria. However, [Japan transit visas are not issued as of now](https://www.mofa.go.jp/j_info/visit/visa/page22e_000999.html). You need to reschedule the flight.

Another remote possibility is, you can get a visa as part of organized tour. But who will organize the tour that caters to your 17 hours 45 minutes is a question.